# How do I select birthdays in the next 30 Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with birthdates and I want to select all the birthdays that will come in the next 30 days.

The situation is, that all the birthdays are written in the form off 1999-09-15 which means that even if I tried selecting the next 30 days, the birthdays wouldn't show up because the year is 1999.

I am running Microsoft Server 2016.

```
SELECT * from dbo.EMPLOYEES
WHERE DATE <= DATEADD(day, +30,GETDATE()) 
and   DATE >= getdate()
order by "DATE"
```

Comment: Dear new User, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the instructions on ["How to ask a question on StackOverflow?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please give us your efforts until now, data, the desired output and everything else we need to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Given 1999 isn't a leap year how are people born on 29th February recorded?

Comment: @BarneyL thats an interesting question. I haven't thought about this due to the fact that there isn't an employee born on 29th of February recorded in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the birthdate, we need to work only on the days and the months, not on the year. Thats why we cannot get Where date between 2 dates.

```
SELECT 
  dateofbirth_c AS BIRTHDAY
 ,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.dateofbirth_c,GETDATE()) / 365.25) AS AGE_NOW
 ,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.dateofbirth_c,GETDATE()+30) / 365.25) AS AGE_30_Days_FROM_NOW
FROM 
  Employees EMP
WHERE 1 = (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.dateofbirth_c,GETDATE()+30) / 365.25))
          -
          (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.dateofbirth_c,GETDATE()) / 365.25))
```

Comment: @ti60r . . . Dividing by 365.25 just doesn't feel right for a problem like this.  I suspect that this sometimes returns 30 days and sometimes either 29 or 31 days.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following; check the month and day because year will not match with birthday year that's why you are not getting any data.

```
SELECT *
from dbo.EMPLOYEES
WHERE month(DATE)>= month(GETDATE()) 
and  day(DATE) >= day (getdate()) and day(DATE) < = day( getdate()) + 30
order by "DATE"
```

Comment: This does not give precise results. lets say we have the date 1990-11-23 it comes out with my query; however it is not true; 
OR the date 2000-01-01 when running this script on 2019-12-31 it will not appear

Answer (score 1):

I'm note sure about microsoft server but on postgres just generate list of days and compare like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE to_char(user_dob, 'MM-DD') IN 
(SELECT to_char(date, 'MM-DD') 
FROM generate_series(current_date, current_date + 30, '1 day') AS date);
```

And now all you have to change that 30 to any days to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.EMPLOYEES
WHERE  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) , MONTH(Date), DAY(Date)) >= GETDATE()
       AND  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) , MONTH(Date), DAY(Date)) <= DATEADD(day, +30, GETDATE())
ORDER BY  Date
```

Comment: Breaks when Date is February 29 and current year is not a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an accurate result that works for leap years and so on, then:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM dbo.EMPLOYEES e CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),
                            MONTH(e.date),
                            DAY(e.date)
                           )
             )
     ) v(this_year_date)
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), this_year_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 29 OR
      DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), DATEADD(year, 1, this_year_date)) BETWEEN 0 AND 29
order by "DATE"
```

Comment: Hey Gordon Linoff, what should I replace (e.date) with?